# Como criar dependencias entre Jobs no Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, windows-service

Tenho um Windows Services onde utilizo [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) para agendar tarefas no meu sistema, porém existem tarefas que só podem ser executadas após a conclusão (com sucesso) de uma outra.

Não achei documentação onde indica essa possibilidade nas triggers.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei, com a utilização de [JobChainingJobListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368054/how-to-chain-more-than-2-jobs-using-jobchainingjoblistener-quartz-net) é possível encadear a execução dos Jobs e isso já resolve meu problema.

Também é possível, no pior dos casos criar um Listener na mão utilizando [IJobListener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html).